# Issue in Inserting value of javascript variable in mysql database using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, google-geolocation

HTML CODE

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

      #map {
        height: 50%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var latitude;
    var longitude;

        function showLocation(position)
        {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude= position.coords.longitude;
            alert("Latitude:"+position.coords.latitude+ "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        }
        function errorHandler(err)
        {
            if(err.code==1)
            {
                alert("error: Access is denied!");
            }
            else if(err.code==2)
            {
                alert("error: Position is unavailable!");
            }
        }
        function getLocation()
        {


    if(navigator.geolocation)
                {
                    var options={timeout:60000};
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation,errorHandler,options);
                }
            else
                { alert("sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");}
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map, infoWindow;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 6
        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDm1MhIYREunq5Kg2wCLcSO2JLkIFdR1Ms&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <form action="geolocator.php"> <input type="button" onclick="getLocation()" method="get" value="Get Location"/> </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php 
   include 'geolocation.html';
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xyz');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'minorproj');
   $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
   $latitude = $_GET["latitude"];
   $longitude = $_GET["longitude"];
   $sql= "INSERT INTO geo (lat,longi) VALUES('$latitude','$longitude')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
 ?>
```

Actually I am able to get values of latituide and longitude both in alert box and there is no other error just problem is that i am not able to get values in my database .
I think i am using some incorrect query or missing something in my code

[image: Output In Alert Box] .

[image: Database Screenshot]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Learn about the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  You need AJAX.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: i know that currently I am running this on my localhost and looking forward  to solve above mentioned issue

Comment: I do not see any place where your browser code (html/js) sends the data to the php script. Did I miss it somewhere?

Comment: got it will include that and see if it works